# Dotless on Appharbor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor, dotless

I am having a huge issues with DotLess on AppHarbor.  I have setup my web.config correctly according to dotless but my .less files are always giving a 404 error.

I have made sure that the files are built as content, that there is a mime-type and that all settings are according to dotless.  But it is still not working... is anyone else having the same issue?  Has anyone else been able to resolve it?

Comment: Can you get the logs? Is it getting as far as asp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to set the **Build Action** value to **Content** and then set the **Copy To Output DIrectory** value to **Copy always**.  After doing that, it seems to work correctly! WOOHOOOO!  This is so exciting.  It's been a big issues of the last few days.

Comment: This solution also helped me when doing font files...brilliant!